# Importing content of local file data into another Angular Component

Tags: angular

I have some mock data in `Customers.mock.ts file`. I am trying to access this data in 2 other files `Customers.component.spec.ts` and `Customers.stories.ts` files.

Here is my code for Customers.mock.ts file

```
export const Customer = {
  Customer: []
};
```

Here is my code for Customers.component.spec.ts file

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/i18n/', '.json');
}



describe('Data', () => {
  let component: Data;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Data>;

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here is my code for Customer.ts

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule()
export class CustomerStoriesComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private localeService: LocaleService) {
    localeService.nameObservable().subscribe((name) => {
      translate.use(name);
    });
    localeService.locale = locale;
  }
}


  };
}
```

How can I get mock data in both spec and stories file so that I do not need to manually keep this data in both the files?

Answer (score 0):

you need export your const at empiricial-percentiles.mock.ts

```
export const empiricalPercentiles = {...}
```

and import in where you want.

```
import {empiricalPercentiles} from 'empiricial-percentiles.mock.ts';
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I have edited my code. After making changes I am getting error in spec file  ` jsonReplacement: component.productCode ? empiricalPercentiles : null,` line saying empiricalPercentiles is never being used. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: whats is the error? your 'jsonReplacement: component.productCode ? empiricalPercentiles : null' line is in a beforeEach function. will be executed before each test.

Comment: It says cannot find name empiricalPercentiles

Comment: because your empiricalPercentiles is a attr of your EmpiricalPercentiles Object. try EmpiricalPercentiles.empiricalPercentiles

Comment: So this is what my mock file looks like **export class EmpiricalPercentiles {
  public empiricalPercentiles = {
    empiricalPercentiles: [
      {
        empiricalPercentile: 99,
        yearlyValueDailyDeviation: 40,
      }**

Comment: if is a mocke data. dont use object. use the file that u describe in the question and access it with this EmpiricalPercentiles.empiricalPercentiles

Comment: I was able to access in spec file but not in stories file -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139484/difficulty-accessing-mock-json-data-into-another-angular-file