# Difficulty accessing mock JSON data into another angular file

Tags: angular

I am trying to access mock JSON data from `data.mock.ts` file into ‘data.stories.ts’ file. I tried writing some code in `getWindowsData` function which is in stories file but I am unable to access the data

Here is my code for data.mock.ts file

```
export class Windows {
  public static readonly Windows = {
    Windows: [
      {
        WindowsValue: 993,
        WindowsYear: 1997,
      },
      {
        WindowsValue: 953,
        WindowsYear: 1873,
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

Here is my code for data.stories.ts file

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(https: https) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(https, './i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule()
export class WindowsStoriesComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private localeService: LocaleService) {
    localeService.nameObservable().subscribe((name) => {
      translate.use(name);
    });
  }
}

      },
    };
  });
```

How can I get the data from mock file to stories file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is accessing the class as whole, Instead you can write in the function you mentiond, like this,

```
export function getEmpiricalPercentilesData(params: HttpParams) {

  // Returning the *empiricalPercentiles* variable(Mock Data) of the class
  return EmpiricalPercentiles.empiricalPercentiles;
}
```

Comment: It is giving following error- TS2576: Property 'empiricalPercentiles' is a static member of type 'EmpiricalPercentiles'

Comment: Oh sorry mate, My bad, static member can be accessed directly without creating the instance of the class, 

I have edited my answer, Please check, and if it works please mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes it worked to certain extent, data is being displayed in Empirical Percentiles column but 2nd column it says N/A, no data is displayed. Any idea?

Comment: Can you create the stackblitz rnvironment for your code, SO I can understand it better.